# Global Coordinates in Differential Geometry?

Tags: geometry, differential

In trying to learn a bit about differential geometry I have hit a puzzler. Most texts emphasize that one coordinate system will not suffice in general, but the reasoning is never given. After all, if a collection of open sets (the domains of the various coordinate mappings) cover the manifold and each is diffeomorphic with an open set of $R^n$, then why can't the local diffeomorphisms be "continued" so as to constitute a mapping of the whole manifold diffeomorphically to $R^n$? (In much the same way that a function analytic on an open set in the complex plane can be analytically extended to the entire plane.)

This would allow one to establish a common origin for the coordinates, thereby placing all the onus of "nonlinearity" on the (global) coordinate mapping.

I'm sure I am missing something, but could someone please tell me precisely what?

Thanks.

Comment: How would this work with $S^1$?

Comment: See my response to James S. Cook below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphere can't be covered by one cooridnate patch. Suppose there is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ diffeomorphic to the whole sphere, note sphere is compact, in particular closed and bounded $\mathbb{R}^3$. By continuity of inverse of the parametrization, the sphere should be open. Hence we know there is an proper subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$ clopen, which contradicts to connectedness of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: nicely argued. Here's the argument he needs.

Comment: Yep! Very nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: John, I think your argument is fine if the sphere is imbedded in $R^3$; however, if the imbedding is in $R^4$ it is no longer valid. (See my "answer" beliw.)I am still a bit confused by the very basic ideas behind differential geometry, and this was undoubtedly reflected in my initial posting. Thanks again for your cogent response.

Comment: Another issue: The Riemann sphere (the one point compactification of the complex plane) is a "practical" counterexample. Except for the north pole, the stereographic projection operator maps the sphere bijectively onto the plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a global coordinate system then the coordinate vector fields are nontrivial on the manifold. However, there exist manifolds where this is not possible. Even something as simple as a sphere. The local nature of coordinates is not an oversight of the theory, it is an essential feature.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a rigorous proof of the impossibility. I will have a look at the sphere. As I recall, three charts suffice; certainly four do. Assuming the latter, we have four open sets and four coordinate maps. The coordinate functions must be compatible on the intersections of the open sets, thus allowing us to extend the mapping on one patch to another. Right?

Comment: There is no homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for topological reasons (one is compact, one is disconnected by the removal of one point).

Comment: there may be a more trivial example than the sphere. Perhaps the Mobius strip would do? That said, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres gives you some ideas. Or, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem . I recall a proof which was an application of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, that took about a semester to build up to.

Comment: For the sphere, you can cover it with two charts, take the Northern hemisphere and a bit more past the equator, then, the Southern hemisphere and a bit above the equator. These overlap on a strip about the equator. But, often we use the charts based on projecting two of the three Cartesian coordinates as those are convenient for some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

First, a function analytic on an open set can not necessarily be analytically continued to all of $\mathbb C$. Take $1\over{z-1}$ on the open unit disc, for an example. Or the $\Gamma$ function, or the Riemann zeta function, or any other meromorphic function. And even better, try exponentiating any of those and you'll be analytic on an open set but have essential singularities in any attempt to extend to the whole plane.

To continue the complex analysis examples, you can see what goes wrong in an attempt to construct a global chart from local ones by considering $\log z$. Pick any branch, and now try to get a single well-defined global version by approaching the branch cut from opposite sides. You will find the imaginary parts disagree by $2\pi i$ no matter what you do.

This is the crux of the issue in a manifold: there is nothing a priori that assures you won't get complete nonsense out of patching things together locally into a global picture. The definition is explicitly local in statement, and the pursuit of theorems that can be stated globally is a generally non-trivial endeavor.

As others have noted, there are standard topological reasons why a given manifold can't be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Connectedness, compactness, homology groups, (higher) fundamental groups, etc. are all preserved by homeomorphisms, and thus diffeomorphisms. For example: $S^n$ is compact, $\mathbb R^n$ is not. Thus they are not diffeomorphic.